# calling jsp from a browser not working even though web.xml entries are proper

Tags: jsp, web.xml

I am trying to call a jsp from browser without giving .jsp extension. Hence added these in web.xml. i have this structure : `.../webapps/reports/web-inf/<other project folders>`. I am keeping my jsp(which is to be called in browser) in myreports folder. Modified web.xml with  this

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myreport</servlet-name> 
  <jsp-file>/reports/myreport.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myreport</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/reports/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It's not working, in the sense, it's not calling this jsp. Can anybody help me to understand what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

The path in the jsp-file tag needs to be relative to your app path. If the jsp file is under web-inf you need a reference to web-inf in there:

```
 <jsp-file>/web-inf/{other_project_folder}/myreport.jsp</jsp-file>
```